# UserProvider is not instantiable when extending Guard in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection

I made a custom guard implementation that force disables "remember me". Specifics of this custom implementation aside - when I try binding it to the Guard Contract it seems something goes wrong.

#### `Customguard.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Contracts\Auth;

use Illuminate\Auth\Guard as StockGuard;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as UserContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard as GuardContract;


class CustomGuard extends StockGuard implements GuardContract
{

  /**
   * Log a user into the application.
   *
   * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable $user
   * @param  bool                                       $remember
   * @return void
   */
  public function login (UserContract $user, $remember = false)
  {
      parent::login($user, false);
  }
}
```

(`Guard->login` is overridden with exactly the same method signature)

I did the binding as follows, in the `boot` method of `app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php`

```
$this->app->bind('Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard', App\Contracts\Auth\CustomGuard::class);
```

Everything works up until the point where CustomGuard->login is invoked.

```
BindingResolutionException in Container.php line 749:
Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider] is not instantiable.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/l5-extending-auth-guard

Comment: Thank you for your reply, and yes, I saw that, and if I don't figure out how to fix what I'm doing right now, I will implement it according to the description given there -- but I would much rather figure out exactly what is wrong with my implementation so that I can learn about the architecture of Laravel.

Answer (score 2):

Userprovider is an interface, you must use the class that implements the interface, I think that is eloquente Userprovidev.

**Changed:**

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider;
```

**To:**

```
use  App\Http\Controllers\Auth\CustomUserProvider as UserProvider;
```